# Docker service process zombie holding a Device Mapper managed device

Tags: linux, docker, device-mapper

I'm running RHEL (kernel 4.1.12) with Docker (1.12.1) and my docker service `dockerd` became a zombie `[dockerd] <defunct>` with `PID 412`

```
# ps -a | grep dockerd
    1   412   412   412 ?           -1 Zsl      0  23:28 [dockerd] <defunct>
```

and it holds resources, in particular a device **251:4** (`/dev/dm-4`) which is a Device Mapper managed:

```
# dmsetup ls
docker-251:0-6815748-pool       (251:1)
docker-251:0-6815748-e97dd950.......59a691feaf6     (251:4)

# lsof | grep 251,4
dockerd     412  6844           root 1257u      BLK              251,4       0t0    2439769 /dev/dm-4
```

as a result, removing the `thin` entry `docker-251:0-6815748-e97dd950.......59a691feaf6` fails

```
# dmsetup remove docker-251:0-6815748-e97dd950.......59a691feaf6
device-mapper: remove ioctl on docker-251:0-6815748-e97dd950.......59a691feaf6 failed: Device or resource busy
Command failed
```

Any suggestions how to cleanup the leftovers of the docker service (e.g., all the DM entries) besides restarting the whole system?

Is it really possible that a zombie process holds resources?

Comment: The question is a good and valid one, but I think it is a better fit for [SF] (or [SU], depending on what the boundary between professional and generic infrastructure is)

Comment: Could it be any underlying 'aufs' mounts used by docker causing the device to be busy? Check /proc/mounts, unmount  any mounts and re-try dmsetup remove

Comment: I see your storage driver is devicemapper, so ignore aufs part, but check /proc/mounts for any mounts

Comment: Yeah, having the DM device mounted would prevent the *remove* operation from being successful; unfortunately, that's not this case. :( but thanks anyway! I even nuked the whole */var/lib/docker* dir and still I'm unable to get rid off the Docker's DM managed devices.

Comment: @StepanVavra did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.